# How to load commerce order based on purchased entity?

Tags: commerce, 10

I know how to load an order based on its properties by following code

```
$orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'default'])
```

Since order items is a referenced entity can I load only orders based on purchased entity? Say I have Product Id ($product_id) I need to load orders based on product id. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get commerce order based on Purchased entity/Product id:**

```
$order_by_product = [];
$orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->loadMultiple();
  foreach ($orders as $order) {
    foreach ($order->getItems() as $order_item) {
      $product_variation = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity();
      // Added condition if product id is 5
      if(isset($product_variation) && $product_variation->getProductId() == 5){
        $order_by_product[$order->id()] = $order;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Background Info:** There is not direct relation between the order & product if explore the commerce module
that indicates there is not any property in order entity to load order by purchased entity/
product id using loadByProperties(), **however by above code can get the order by product id**

Comment: Hai thanks for replying. Ya even I couldn't find. Loading all orders will be bit heavy I guess. I was able to filter orders based on product id using views. So I thought what if there is a possibility.